# Communications link failure when connecting to MySQL database from Java

Tags: java, mysql, database

If I specify a URL like `jdbc:mysql://localhost/database`, then it works. If I specify either a local or remote IP address it doesn't work. Do I need to change any network settings, etc? The platform is Ubuntu.

Comment: Perhaps mysql user permissions. Add user/ grants. My.cnf bind-address. Could be 1 of about 5 things

Comment: Please post more details, including sample code and a full copy-pasted error message. We cannot really help you with the information you have given here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` in mysql to allow external ip address

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Answer (score 0):

1) change my.conf (whatever your mysql conf file is called). And set bind-address to 0.0.0.0 as it is prob 127.0.0.1

2) stop/restart mysql daemon

3) add database user perhaps coming in from diff ip addr

```
CREATE USER 'fred7'@'192.168.2.7' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';
```

4) grants

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test7db.* TO 'fred7'@'192.168.2.7';
```

5) firewall

For 3 and 4, let's say the mysql server is on aws ec2 and i am sitting at a public library using sqlyog or workbench. That prog will alert me if connect failure stating something like `connection failed for user 'fred7'@'gfs6.nyc.comcastbusiness.net'`. So it is pretty obvious how to do 3 and 4 then.

Good luck!